# Take Screenshot in iOS 8 with Objective C doesn'work

Tags: objective-c, ios8

i have written an App that takes screenshots. If the user enables this feature the app uses a background queue to take screenshots.

In iOS7 everything works fine but with iOS 8 there are only send white Screenshots to the server.

I use this method to take a screenshot:

```
 CGImageRef cgScreen = UIGetScreenImage();
    if (cgScreen) {
        result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgScreen];
        CGImageRelease(cgScreen);
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Why don't you do homework about UIGetScreenImage?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I could not find the Apple's official documentation about the method `UIGetScreenImage()` but I have read so many stackoverflow entries saying that has been removed in iOS8 and especially iOS7 with 64bit binaries.

I am using following method to make screenshot and which is working from `iOS 5 to iOS 8` without any problem.

```
- (void)makeScreenShotWithView:(UIView *)view scale:(float)scale {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, scale);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

if you want to make the whole screen as screenshot then pass a `window` object for an example `view.window`.

Try this

Comment: This method also works, but it doesn't take the same screenshot like the other method. It doesn't work with UIAlertView or UIActionSheet. Also the status bar isn't displayed. UIGetScreenImage() take a screenshot of the whole display/window with UIAlertView and UIActionSheet in it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] as the `view`.

Comment: This is a litte bit better than before but finally it is not the same qualitiy like before. The statusbar still isn't visible in the screenshot.

Comment: Use the scale factor like 2.0 or 4.0 to increase the quality.

Comment: The quality of the image is ok! The problem is that the screenshot doesn't catch the whole window like before.